# nginx configuration for multiple sites one ip address and one server

Tags: nginx, multisite, nginx-config

nginx multiple websites on same port and one ip address

for example my ip 192.167.10.2

and we want to run site on same ip
nginx/html contain two project like below

1: project1
2: project2

we run default project1 on ip :192.167.10.2 
and second project run like 192.167.10.2/project2

how do configuration in nginx config file

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example.You could try

First config :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/mywebsite1;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name mywebsite1.de www.mywebsite1.de;

    location / {
    try_files $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www/mywebsite1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Second config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 //@here Be carefull , only one default

    root /var/www/mywebsite2;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name mywebsite1.de www.mywebsite1.de;

    location / {
        try_files $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www/mywebsite1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to restart server.